# Release Management for Visual Studio - Not Working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, release-management, ms-release-management

Anybody able to successfully install/configure Release Management Server for TFS/Visual Studio 2013?

Went through simple install of SQL Express 2014/Release Management Server on both Win 8.1 Pro and Win Server 2012 R2 and the attached image is the result.

Interface appears to be missing many components, as if permission or some other IIS setting is incorrect.

Tried in both Chrome and IE with the same result.

Used default install settings (Network Service account) and currently running SQL Express on same machine as Release Management install.

[image: Release Management Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *is* the interface for RM's Release Explorer and it does look like that, unbelievable as it may seem. All this will change with new RM components in TFS 2015 - check out Donovon Brown's [talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/3-649) at Build 2015 for a preview.

Back to the root of your issue, which is that Release Explorer is only a minor part of the RM stack. Have you installed the RM client (a WPF application) which is the main interface for configuring RM? My continuous delivery with TFS blog post series [here](http://pleasereleaseme.net/continuous-delivery-with-tfs/) has all the details you need.

Comment: When trying to connect via a client, an error is returned: "The server specified could not be reached. Please ensure the information that is entered is valid (please contact your Release Management administrator for assistance). Same error appears even when client is installed on the same machine.

Comment: Looks like URL was incorrect. Now the error is "current user does not have access to Release Management". Workstation is not part of a domain and can see via Fiddler that correct username/domain is not being passed. Any way to have client pass domain account?

Comment: In absence of domain you need to use shadow accounts, ie same username and password on all machines involved. The account that is used to install the server components gets added as an RM admin and for the first client installation you'll need to use that admin account as it's the only one with privileges to connect. If you are not logged in to a remote machine with that (shadow) account you can do a Run As on the installation exe but account needs to be present. In a demo environment you can perform the first client installation on the server machine and then add other accounts as required.